# Understanding opcodes in Z80 emulator

Tags: z80

I'm currently working with an Z80 processor emulator, as a beginner I found an example with values assigned to the memory in order to show "Hello World!".

```
1. 0x21, 0x0C, 0X00,// ld hl, 0008
2. 0x06, 0x0F, // ld b,0f
3. 0x7e, // ld a,(hl)
4. 0x23, // inc hl
5. 0xD3, 0x00, // out (00), a
6. 0x10, 0xFA, // djnz
7. 0x76, // halt
8. 0x48, 0x65, 0x6C, 0x6C, 0x6F, // Hello
9. 0x2D, 0x77, 0x6F, 0x72, 0x6C, //  Worl  
10. 0x64, 0x21, 0x20, 0x21//d! !
```

I have some questions about the values in memory:

1. In the first line, for the command `0x21` defines the `LD HL,XX` instruction, so it would be  `LD HL,0CH` in assembler, what is that `0x00` doing there? I thought `LD HL,xx` is a 16-bit instruction so is complementing the `0C` with eight zeros but I think that is not correct.
2. In line #5, what is the `OUT (00),A` doing exactly? I found with some research that `OUT` transfers the data from acumulator to the output port, but is not so clear for me what is doing with that `0x00` specially.

I would really appreciate any hint or help with my questions, thanks in advance for taking the time to read them.

Comment: `LD HL, XX` loads a 16-bit value into `HL`. It takes two bytes to specify a 16-bit value. In line 5, `00` is the port number. It sounds like you need to learn Z80 assembly language before you can dive in to write an emulator.

Comment: And the code is incorrectly copy & pasted. It is `Hello-world! !`, which is only 14 bytes long, while DJNZ is initialised to loop 15 times. :) HL is, obviously, loaded with address 0x000C not 0x0008 as the comment claims.

Comment: @tum_ Now I'm confused with```DJNZ``` range, where is that ```15``` given?  as I'm checking the table ```0xFA``` is an opcode for ```JP M,XX```.Thanks in advance for your attention.

Comment: `10 n         DJNZ PC + n`  - so 10(hex) is the opcode, FA (== -6) is the offset to jump to. DJNZ decrements register B, compares it to 0, if non-zero - jump, otherwise - fall through. B is set to 0F which is 15.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering your questions:

1. `0x21` is the op-code for the three-byte `LD HL, nn` instruction. The `nn` part is a 16-bit immediate operand. In Z80 all 16-bit immedidates are encoded in the little-endian order of bytes, meaning the byte that contains the least significant bits (LSB) comes first and is followed by the byte that contains the most significant bits (MSB) of the value. In your example the bytes are `0x0c, 0x00`. The resulting 16-bit value is thus `0x000c` and the instruction is `ld hl, 0x000c`, even though the comment mentions a different value.
2. `out (n), a` is a Z80 instruction that outputs the value of the register `a` to a port. Despite that Z80 ports have 16-bit addresses (just like memory addresses), the `n` operand that specifies the port is an 8-bit immediate. This immediate goes to the low byte of the full port address whereas the high byte of the address is the value of the register `a`. Here's what it looks like in my emulator:

```cpp
    void on_out_n_a(fast_u8 n) {
        fast_u8 a = self().on_get_a();
        self().on_output_cycle(make16(a, n), a);
        self().on_set_wz(make16(a, inc8(n)));
    }
```

[OUT (n), A](https://github.com/kosarev/z80/blob/8609eca52bba950421e3aec778c3f6f572be1e33/z80.h#L3236)

What happens on the hardware level is, the processor sets its signal lines, such as  ~IORQ, ~RD, ~WR and the address bus pins, to a specific state so that peripheral devices connected to the processor can recognize the output cycle and "see" which value and to which port is written. You can find further details on what happens during the output cycle in the Z80 user manual, section "Input or Output Cycles".

[Z80 User Manual](https://www.zilog.com/appnotes_download.php?FromPage=DirectLink&dn=UM0080&ft=User%20Manual&f=YUhSMGNEb3ZMM2QzZHk1NmFXeHZaeTVqYjIwdlpHOWpjeTk2T0RBdlZVMHdNRGd3TG5Ca1pnPT0=)

For your emulator to be able to actually output values to peripheral devices you would need that devices, be they real or emulated ones, to be acknowledged of the output and provided with the port address and the output value, so they could figure out if they should react and how specifically they should do that. For example, in ZX Spectrum the three lowest bits of the output port 0xfe (decimal 254) determine the color of the screen border. A Spectrum emulator would thus catch writings to that port, extract the color code from the value and update the screen to show the border of the new color.